# run multiple instances of Rethinkdb on the same machine

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I would like to run multiple instances of Rethinkdb on the same machine. 
Is that possible? if so, what is the set up?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer:

https://rethinkdb.com/docs/start-a-server/

Multiple RethinkDB instances on a single machine
Adding a node to a RethinkDB cluster is as easy as starting a new RethinkDB process and pointing it to an existing node in the cluster. Everything else is handled by the system without any additional effort required from the user.

Now start the second RethinkDB instance on the same machine:

$ rethinkdb --port-offset 1 --directory rethinkdb_data2 --join localhost:29015
info: Creating directory /home/user/rethinkdb_data2
info: Listening for intracluster connections on port 29016
info: Attempting connection to 1 peer...
info: Connected to server "Chaosknight" e6bfec5c-861e-4a8c-8eed-604cc124b714
info: Listening for client driver connections on port 28016
info: Listening for administrative HTTP connections on port 8081
info: Server ready